# How to use template string to create link from props and render image in React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a link to import image asset based on ID available on props. Example asset is p4916.png where 4196 is ID available on props.data.player.id

I have checked in debugger that **img** correctly builds the url equal to commented out url import, but when I use reference to it in **src={img}** it is being ignored, using **src={url}** exactly the same string works

Any extra step to do? This is a part of create-react-app set up btw

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//import url from '../assets/p4916.png';

const PlayerStats = (props) => {

  const team = props.data.player.currentTeam.name

  debugger
  const img = `../assets/p${props.data.player.id}.png`

  const first_name = props.data.player.name.first
  const last_name = props.data.player.name.last
  const position = props.data.player.info.positionInfo

  return (
    <div>
      <div key={last_name}></div>
      <div className="card__player-image"><img src={img} alt="" /></div>
      <div className="card__club-badge"><div className={team}>{team}</div></div> 

      <div className="card__info">
        <div className="info">{first_name} {last_name}</div>
        <div className="info">{position}</div>
      </div>

      <div className="card__stats-group">  
        <div className="stats-group__item">Appearances<span className="stats-group__item-data">1</span></div>
        <div className="stats-group__item">Goals<span className="stats-group__item-data">2</span></div>
        <div className="stats-group__item">Assists<span className="stats-group__item-data">3</span></div>
        <div className="stats-group__item">Goals per match<span className="stats-group__item-data">4</span></div>
        <div className="stats-group__item">Passes per minute<span className="stats-group__item-data">5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default PlayerStats;
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work with an absolute path like that you are using because of create-react-app. CRA's dev server uses images like this: `static/media/your_img_name.somerandomid.jpg` So, when you use it with an absolute path it does not work.

Before building your app there isn't a `static` directory, but this is how devserver work in development mode. After building your app you can see this directory in your `build` directory with your file with the same name CRA gave to it.

If you are working with an image upload system or your app does some kind of operations with a backend server you need to find some better ways.

If there is not a backend server and you just want to solve this issue easily I think you can use `require`:

```
<div className="card__player-image"><img src={require(`../assets/p${props.data.player.id}.png`)} alt="" /></div>
```

Yes, not a decent way of doing this. But I don't know any better way, I hope there is one.

Comment: Thank you @devserkan src={require(img)} doesn'work, yes I was looking for quick fix, no server   ```Error: Cannot find module "."
webpackMissingModule
src/components/player_stats.js:22
  19 | return (
  20 |   <div>
  21 |     <div key={last_name}></div>
> 22 |     <div className="card__player-image"><img src={require(img)} alt="" /></div>
  23 |     <div className="card__club-badge"><div className={team}>{team}</div></div> 
  24 |     
  25 |     <div className="card__info">
```

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it does not work either, sorry for misleading your. It seems you need to use the path in the require. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Again, you are welcome. If my answer helped you please consider accepting it.